# Bitcoind rpc AddLocal(ip:port) and Disover: IPv4 eth0: ip missing Amazon AWS CentOS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, centos, json-rpc, bitcoind

I have a server at DigitalOcean with Ubuntu installed and bitcoind with rpc which IS working.

With my Amazon AWS CentOs server bitcoin-cli is working but not EasyBitcoin-PHP, it's returning 0:

```
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('username','password','myipaddress','8332');

echo "Status: ".$bitcoin->status;
```

Bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=myipaddress
```

Checkout this image. On the working DigitalOcean Ubuntu server it includes `AddLocal(192.81.219.224:18333,1)` AND `Discover: IPv4 eth0: 192.81.219.224`[image]

I also tried to add `-discover=1` to the AWS CentOS but it didn't do anything new and still isn't working.

I'm guessing it may have to do with Amazon's Elastic IP's or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Amazon AWS apparently limits httpd network connections initially.